# How to group the same class within different templates in xslt file

Tags: xslt

`<xsl:template  name="Questions">`

`<xsl:if test="$object-display = 'true'">`

`<div class="{string($objectClass)}">`

`<user id="1" name="ABC"/>`

`</div>   </xsl:if>`

`<xsl:if test="$change-display = 'true'">`

`<div class="ChangeDisplay">`

`<user id="2" name="EFG"/>`

`</div>`

`</xsl:if>`

`</xsl:template>`

`<xsl:template  name="Answers">

<xsl:if test="$object-display = 'true'">

```
   <user id="3" name="HIJ"/>
```

<xsl:if test="$change-display = 'true'">

```
 <user id="4" name="KLM"/>
```

`

`</xsl:template>`

```
<xsl:template  name="QuestionWithAnswers">
```

```
  <xsl:if test="$object-display = 'true'">
```

```
  <div class="{string($objectClass)}">
```

```
    <user id="5" name="NOP"/>
```

```
    </div> 
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="$change-display = 'true'">
```

```
  <div class="ChangeDisplay">
```

```
    <user id="6" name="QRS"/>
```

```
   </div>
</xsl:if>
```

```
</xsl:template>
```

In this xslt file, I want to group only change display condition inside the same xslt file

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing an example input, your current XSLT and the expected output. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: every templates has 2 same conditions. i need to group one of the condition in each template

Comment: This description is not useful. Please edit your question and provide enough code to enable us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your code formatting is unclear. Please edit the question, and copy and paste your code again, after reading this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting